# Django: Automatically setting empty strings in model fields to None?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to iterate over my model fields within a Django model and check if they are empty string and replace them with a null in the model save() method programmatically. This is because some CharFields need to be unique or have no value.

Example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
    nick_name = models.CharField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
    ...
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field in self._meta.fields: # get the model fields
            if field=='':
                field = None
       super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The above complains about a creation_counter which is unclear why an attempt to compare those values instead of the field value with the empty string is done.

This could be done manually, but I have too many models....

Any suggestions?

edit:
Thanks to everyone who attempted to help me! :D

The solution that seems to work for me is posted by Jazz, but his code isn't showing up in his post. This is my version which is essentially identical, but with an extra check to make sure we are only overriding when necessary:

```
from django.db.models.Field import CharField as _CharField

class CharField(_CharField):
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.blank == self.null == self.unique == True and value == '':
            value = None

        return super(CharField).get_db_prep_value(value, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: _meta.fields probably contains more than just the model fields.  have you tried this on individual fields successfully?  Also, what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case, I would suggest a custom model field, which subclasses a `CharField` and ensures  that a empty string is converted to `None` -- overriding `get_db_prep_value` should do it.

```
class EmptyStringToNoneField(models.CharField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value == '':
            return None  
        return value

class Person(models.Model):
    name = EmptyStringToNoneField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
    nick_name = EmptyStringToNoneField(blank=True, unique=True, null=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: That sounds like an excellent solution. I will post my code as answer. edit: attempting to edit your post, I realized you have posted some code that is not showing up at all in my browser. I will mark yours as the answer, but my code does a little extra check. Will be added to my post.

Comment: What would you do if you need a similar feature for URLField, but need verify_exist=True? i..e no URL validation needed for empty url? It get's a little complex due to the form is involved as well and will do it's own validation.

Comment: In this case, just use `blank=True` ;-) and the same code above!

Comment: That won't work, because when verify_exist is set to True, the field will validate that the URL works and is reachable. As far as I can tell the URLValidator doesn't check the blank so will throw a URL appears broken exception.

Comment: Certainly it will: `verify_exists` is default to `True`; if you provide None, or '' the URLValidator passes and your model gets saved.

Comment: Thanks, you are indeed correct. I verified it. I will have to comb the code to spot that, since I didn't see anything on first (or second) glance that indicated it ignored blank URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Jazz's answer works like a charm for me.

I just want to point out that if you are using South migration tool, the `schemamigration` command will fail, unless you specify a **introspect rule** for the new custom field.

For "simple fields", you can simply add the following code to wherever your field is specified.

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^myapp\.stuff\.fields\.SomeNewField"])
```

Now the South migration should work.

FYI.

Reference: http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork